# How to show my reset password page in React using Django Rest Framework and Dj-rest-auth

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

I have an app that has a React front end and a Django api backend. I'm trying to get the password reset page to work but I can't work out how to set up the urls/routing. I had it working locally, but I think that was because the ports for the frontend and backend are different locally, so they were essentially different domains.

My Django url patterns includes:

```
path('api/v1/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm')
```

I have a catchall url in my Django urls to make the rest of the frontend work.

My React Router includes:

```
<Route path="/api/v1/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token/" component={ResetPassword} />
```

My React password reset page contains:

```
    let url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH + '/api/v1/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/' + this.props.match.params.uid + '/' +  this.props.match.params.token + '/';
    let headers = {token: this.props.match.params.token, 
                    uid: this.props.match.params.uid, 
                    new_password1: this.state.newPassword, 
                    new_password2: this.state.newPasswordConf
                  }
    axios
      .post(url, headers)
```

This takes the token and uid from the password reset link then sends them, along with the user's new password to the password reset endpoint.

The dilemma seems to be, I need to access the reset link via React to be able to get the token and uid, but then I need to access the same link as a call to the API to be able to reset the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve it using a slightly cheeky way.

I simply overrode the template for the password reset email, using the default template, but just adding something extra to the url. Just so the url is different in some way.

I copied [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html) template to `templates/registration`

Then just added an extra word (`email` - but could be any word) to the path that gets created in the email:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/email{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

Now I can use this new path in my my React Router to get the uid and token, but when I submit the data to the api I use the 'proper' url (the one in my Django urlpatterns)